# How to solve Undefined-Control-Sequence Error for biblatex in AucTeX

Tags: biblatex, auctex

After reading many great things about biblatex in the forum, I would like to start using it. I tried the steps given in [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex) on a file on which I am already using BibTeX, but received an Undefined-Control-Sequence error on `\addbibresource`.

I set up an example document copying from the files in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex//doc/examples, (`01-introduction.tex` and `biblatex-examples.bib`) and got the same error.

I am using AucTeX 11.866 with TeXLive 2009. Below is the document I am trying to compile, along with the error it outputs. I am using the Default engine and generating a PDF (or trying to). What should I do to make this work?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

% biblatex-examples.bib is located in ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Name of first section here}

This is just filler text \parencite{companion}.

This is just filler text \parencite[59]{companion}.

This is just filler text \parencite[see][]{companion}.

This is just filler text \parencite[see][59--63]{companion}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.11 \addbibresource
                    {biblatex-examples.bib}
--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AUCTeX has nothing to do with this. The problem is that `\addbibresource` has been added to biblatex from version 1.2, which is not in TeX Live 2009.

The best is to upgrade by downloading MacTeX 2010 from http://tug.org/mactex and running TeX Live Manager to get an up-to-date distribution (I assume you are on Mac OS X from the

```
% biblatex-examples.bib is located in ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/
```

line).

Comment: To use the older `biblatex` version included in TeX Live 2009, replace `\addbibresource{<name>.bib}` with `\bibliography{<name>}`.

Comment: It's going to be a couple of days before I can upgrade and verify this, but you make a strong point. Thanks for the answer!